# How can I remove Tableview Cell after specific index?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have tableView[And I want data like in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABweq.png)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.time.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = bookedTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bookedTableCell", for: indexPath) as! bookedTableCell
    
    cell.timeLbl.text = self.time[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    
    let timeAv = self.temDictForSlots[indexPath.row]["isDataAvailable"] as! Bool
    if timeAv  {
        cell.mainView.isHidden = false
        cell.startTimeLbl.text = self.temDictForSlots[indexPath.row]["sTime"] as? String ?? ""
        cell.endTimeLbl.text = self.temDictForSlots[indexPath.row]["eTime"] as? String ?? ""
        cell.servicesLbl.text = self.temDictForSlots[indexPath.row]["serviceName"] as? String ?? ""
        cell.captionLbl.text = self.temDictForSlots[indexPath.row]["note"] as? String ?? ""
    }
    else {
        cell.mainView.isHidden = true
    }
    if self.sortedTimeArr.contains(self.time[indexPath.row]) == false {
        
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.timeLbl.text = ""
        tableView.rowHeight = 0
        cell.isHidden = true
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
    return cell
}
```

I did the **rowhight = 0** After getting my data but when I scroll it up from the end then it does all cells **rowhight = 0**
But I want after getting data tableview just stopped. It gives no more cells.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: As I understand the image you provide, you still want a cell (like for 05:00 AM), but just want to skip the blue part (the `cell.mainView`) - is this correct?

Comment: Row height sets the height of all of the rows in the table. You need to use `heightForRow(at:)` to return individual row heights

Comment: Yes sir.(cell.mian is a blue view).It is  correct.

Comment: So why would you set the rowHeight to zero? Just hide or show the `mainView`, as you already do, and I get the result.

Comment: Thank you sir.My work has been done.

Comment: If it's done, you should close the question.